# ssrs RDL from Visual Studio 2013 to 2017

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

For many versions I have a reporting services project in Visual Studio.  The latest is Visual Studio 2013.  I have installed Visual Studio 2017 community edition and it has the Microsoft Reporting Services Projects extension.  It also says that it has Data Tools installed as part of VS (at least that's what it looks like).  Yet my rptproj file will not be recognized by Visual studio 2017.  Every document that I'm sent to says I need SqlServer Data Tools but is that now a separate program I have to use to deal with reports outside of Visual Studio?  It makes no sense to me given that there is a reporting Services projects in VS.  But that isn't working at all. I've tried creating a new project and copying the RDL over to it. It opens it and I can see designer but when I try to preview I get the dreeded " Unknown report version 9".   Any help would be very very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just download and install

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

SSDT will provide all the missing bits for VS2017. You will then be able to edit your reports in VS2017 but you will need to upgrade the solutions. You will be promoted to do this upgrade when you attempt to open the project/solution.

Comment: sounded like a great idea.  Except the very simple, almost no input install, came back with "Setup Failed" Recursion too deep; stack overflowed 0x800703E9.   that was AFTER i rebooted to make sure I had as much free resources as possible.  Step by painful step

Comment: Hmmm... I think there was another reply on here earlier about installing something else but it seems to have been deleted. If you installed anything else to resolve this then I would uninstall it and try again. You might need .net frameworks up to date but other than that you should need nothing more than VS2017 and SSDT . That's all I used (albeit VS2017 pro)

Comment: your right there is a missing answer with my comments.  Interesting.  Basically that just said be up to date which I checked.  I'm not finding much with this error message in searches so lucky me, i must be the unique one.